# Inertia.js изменение состояния компонентов в зависимости от параметров url браузера

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertia

Inertia + Laravel + Vue 3

Возможно ли, работая с инерцией.js, сделать меню навигации которое будет открываться и закрываться в зависимости от того есть ли в url браузера параметр `?nav=open` или нет? И чтобы при этом анимация открытия/закрытия меню всегда срабатывала, и чтобы кнопки навигации браузера работали корректно?

Возможно моих знаний не хватает для данной задачки, но я уже пробовал решить её и с помощью методов инерции, и с помощью historyAPI, но всегда либо не срабатывали vue анимации, либо проблемы с кнопками навигации, либо страница заново грузится с сервера и менюшка долго открывается.. Если кто-нибудь нашел решения данной проблемы, буду очень благодарен